# Solve for y $\frac{y!}{(y-2)!2!}+10y=108$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, quadratics

I did $$\frac{y!}{(y-2)!2}+10y=108\\$$

I don't really know how to go from here...

This equation is actually part of a system:

$$\begin{cases}{}^xC_2 = 45 \\ {}^yC_2 + xy = 108\end{cases}$$

Solving the first part of the system I find that x = 10.

My questions:

- How do I solve $\frac{y!}{(y-2)!2!}+10y=108$
- Would it be simpler to solve x and y by solving the system, instead
  of the isolated equations?
- How do I solve the system?

NOTE: C here is the C from the formula of combinations, as in: 
$${}^nC_k = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$$

Comment: Least common denominators

Comment: Why the $+10y$ in the numerator?

Comment: @SimpleArt Oops...

Comment: @SimpleArt I fixed it now

Comment: And answer below?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you meant to solve $\frac{y!}{(y-2)!2!}+10y=108$,

$$\frac{y!}{(y-2)!}=y(y-1)=y^2-y$$

$$\frac{y!}{(y-2)!2!}+10y=0.5y^2+9.5y=108$$

$$y^2+19y=216$$

Quadratic, with solution given as

$$y=8,-27$$

Usually $y>0$, so then $y=8$.

Comment: Only the positive root is strictly valid.  The negative one fails to provide well-defined factorials in the original equation.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Yeah, I guess that's true too.

Comment: @OscarLanzi: Good observation, +1. Much as $x=0$ is a solution of the equation $x^2=0$ but not of the equation $\frac{1/x}{1/x^3}=0$.

Answer (score 2):

$$y^2+19y=216$$
$$y(y+19)=(8)(27)$$
so the $$y=8$$